# Python will not open a module within my .py file

Tags: python-3.x

I was working on some code which retrieves a line in a text file ("save[#]) with the format: 
"[name],[boolean or integer value]"
(The aim is to be able to retrieve it for save states of a game)
The issue is that whenever I try to return a value from my module I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "//IHS-FS-001.ihs.local/Cohort2020$/2ELGAG1/python/srctg/test.py", line 5, in <module>
retrieve()
    File "//IHS-FS-001.ihs.local/Cohort2020$/2ELGAG1/python/srctg/test.py", line 3, in retrieve
    if retrieve.check("test", 1) == True:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'check'
```

The test attribute is a testing module set up to test the code for the game:

```
import retrieve.py
def retrieve():
    if retrieve.check("test", 1) == True:
        return True
retrieve()
```

The retrieve attribute itself is set up like so:

```
import error
def check(i_name, save):
    save = str(save)
    save_n = "save" + save + ".txt"
    save_f = open(save_n, "r")
    list = save_f.readlines()
    for item in range(len(list)):
        list[item] = list[item].strip()
        list[item] = list[item].split(",")
        list[item][1] = list[item][1]
    for item in range(len(list)):
        if i_name == list[item][0]:
            i_return = list[item][1]
    if bool_check(i_return) == True:
        i_return = bool(i_return)
    elif int_check(i_return) == True:
        i_return = int(i_return)
    else:
        print(error.code("001"))
        return "error"
    return i_return
def int_check(value):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(value)
            return True
            break
        except ValueError:
            return False
            break
def bool_check(value):
    while True:
        try:
            value = bool(value)
            return True
            break
        except ValueError:
            return False
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include the `.py` in the import. This tries to import a module named `py` inside the package named `retrieve`, which is probably not what you meant.

```
import retrieve as retrieve_module

def retrieve():
    if retrieve_module.check("test", 1) == True:
        return True
```

Also, don't write a function with the same name as the module you just imported. Change the name of one or the other. That's why it can't find the `.check` attribute. It's looking inside the `retrieve` function instead of inside the `retrieve` module because you overwrote it in the global namespace (by executing the function definition) before you called the function.